# Is it possible to substitute adjacent characters in a string using regex if count is 2?

Tags: regex, perl

String: abc aa efg a aaa hijk aazzz

Using regex, I would like to substitute only the 2 adjacent "a" into a single "a".

1. aa to a
2. aazzz to azzz

My code is this but it also substitutes the 3 "a".

```
s/(aa)/a/g;
```

Comment: aaa should just remain as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookarounds come in handy here, and we can try matching `aa` on the condition that both what comes before `aa` and after it is not another `a`.  Use this pattern:

```
(?<!a)aa(?!a)
```

Here is a working code snippet (demo below):

```
my $old = 'abc aa efg a aaa hijk aazzz';
my $new = $old =~ s/(?<!a)aa(?!a)/a/rg;
print $new;

abc a efg a aaa hijk azzz
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks I tried it. It works for "aa" but "aazzz" should also be "azzz".

Comment: Sorry. It seems to work by adding the "g" modifier. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Though some parts of the regex code I still don't understand but I will try to learn it one by one. Thanks again for the very quick help on this.